# What is dart concept about data streams?

Tags: serialization, websocket, dart, data-stream

Dart changing rapidly so I did not find a way to get data stream from HttpResponse to send arbitrary (even binary) data via websocket. Even file IO has no openInput/OutputStream for now. What is concept for working with data streams in dart at this time?

I'd actually like to get kind of abstract data stream object (like System.IO.Stream in C#) to implement serialization interface with it and then apply it to websocket data stream, so I can change serialization format for my network packets with new serializer implementations in future, or create memory stream object (like System.IO.MemoryStream in C#) to get serialized data in memory.

And finally - is it possible to send binary data with websockets at all?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpRequest` in `dart:io` implements `Stream<List<int>>`. To get the data listen on the stream. An example has recently been added to the API doc at http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpRequest.html. The `http_server` package at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http_server contains a number of utility classes to handle HTTP.

`WebSocket` implements both `Stream` and `StreamSink`. When listeming on the stream the objects received will be of type `String` or `List<int>` depending on whether a string message or a binary data message was sent. Likewise you can add objects of type `String` and `List<int>` to the `WebSocket` to send messages.

The binary data received will be of type `Uint8List` from the `dart:typed_data` library. I will recommend to use `Uint8List` when sending binary data.

As `WebSocket` uses streams all the features for streams including transformation are available.

Comment: Does it means I must always use WebSocket.add to write data and HttpRequest(Stream).listen to read data from streams? This looks ugly. I have async bidirectional binary protocol here and have no idea how to implement it using dart. Sounds like I must read everything into memory and just then unserialize and same when sending data back.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've found WebSocket.listen method also usable. But that's does not change anything in terms of memory overhead.